# Gitlab redirects to 404 page after successful login

Tags: gitlab

After a successful login (using correct username and password) to Gitlab, we are greeted with a `404 The page you're looking for could not be found.` while page is being redirected to `http://gitlab.local/users/undefined`

Once, after hitting this page, if we go to home page `http://gitlab.local/` (or removing the `/users/undefined` part from the URL and hitting enter), everything works fine and we are in the dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is observed that, this happens only in `Firefox` browser and that too with `Lastpass` extention enabled. Using any browser other than Firefox or disabling Lastpass extension does the trick.

It is observed from the trace that, when we first bring up the page `http://gitlab.local`, three calls hit the server:

```
http://gitlab.local/users/sign_in 
http://gitlab.local/users/undefined
http://gitlab.local/users/sign_in
```

and then, Lastpass fills the login data and once we click on login, we are redirected to http://gitlab.local/users/undefined page which throws 404 error.

After disabling Lastpass extension and restarting Firefox, only one call goes to server (instead of three):

```
http://gitlab.local/users/sign_in
```

and this time, the page comes up properly. Offering Lastpass NOT to remember Gitlab password doesn't help either.